# Aquiring a short-lived ID token for Cloud Run in React JS using google-auth-library

Tags: reactjs, google-api-nodejs-client, google-cloud-iam

I have a React JS project, that lets users log in via my own Keycloak-based ID provider, returning a JWT token in case of successful authentication.

I'd like to use this token to acquire a short-lived ID token from Google Cloud to invoke a Cloud Run endpoint.

All GCP configuration has been set up correctly since I can get this token if I invoke the proper endpoints by hand, but I'd like to automate it from my React app. AFAIK the `google-auth-library` has the functionality implemented that lets me get this token, but when I `npm i google-auth-library` it in my project and start the app, I get a plethora of errors akin to this:

```
BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "util": require.resolve("util/") }'
        - install 'util'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "util": false }
```

Is there a way for me to prevent these errors from happening? I already tried `react-app-rewrite` without much success.

React version: 18.2.0
google-auth-library version: 8.7.0

Comment: Please add which function of google-auth-library you want to use.

Comment: not 100% sure which ones exactly. What I want to do is impersonate a service account with a jwt token from an external ID provider, and acquire a short-lived id token

Answer (score 1):

You are facing the error cause `google-auth-library` is a node.js library and not a react js library.

You should not use `google-auth-library` in React.js frontend cause it'll pose a security threat.

You can find and use API calls for the same function you are going to use in the google-auth-library.

Or else create a node js server which does these things for your frontend.

Comment: what should I use then?